# Is every compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the countable union of compact rectangles?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

The question that I've been asking myself is

$$\bbox[#AAFFAF,2pt,border: 2px solid green]{\text{Given a compact set $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, does there exist a countable family of compact rectangles $\{R_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $K=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}R_i$?}}$$

Where we say that $R\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact rectangle if the following condition holds
$$\forall 1\leq j\leq n\ \exists a_j\leq b_j\in\mathbb{R}:R=\prod_{j=1}^n [a_j,b_j]$$
Notice that, clearly, every compact rectangle is compact. Also, if $a=b$, we consider the definition $[a,b]=[a,a]=\{a\}$. Now: I know that, since every open/closed (open or closed; not necessarily clopen) set can be written as a countable union of compact sets, the affirmation of this question would imply that every open/closed set could also be written (in theory) as a countable union of compact rectangles. But I can't find any counterexample which makes me think this might be true (however, I have no idea on how to prove it then)... Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: A circular arc in the plane contains no rectangles (except degenerate ones, singletons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cantor set is a counterexample. It contains no non-degenerate intervals, and it is uncountable so it cannot be a union of singletons.